How to define the if else condition under the pool in azure devops pipeline
I have defined if else condition in in the Azure devops build template as shown below. However in my pool i have three machines and during my build phase it seems the third machine is getting picked not from these two.
stages:

- stage: "BuildStage"
  displayName: "Build Stage"
  jobs:
    - job: "BuildJob"
      displayName: "BuildJob"
      pool:
       ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/dev') }}:
          name: deployment
          agent: bastionvm
       ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/acc') }}:
          name: deployment
          agent: accvm

I have checked twice that i am running the dev branch, so it should pickup the dev branch agent i.e. bastionvm. But its picking up the different agent.

Syntax is invalid, there's no agent property - see pool definition

Is agent: bastionvm supposed to be a demand?

Thanks @RuiJarimba since it is a private pool, it should have been Demands.

As @RuiJarimba mentioned, to use different agent in same agent pool, you need to use demands to filter capability.

@SharatBhaskar did my answer helped you solve your problem?

@RuiJarimba yes your answer was helpful.

If I understood correctly, you want to choose which build agent will run the job depending on the branch.
Try something like this:
variables:
  - ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/features/dev') }}:
      - name: buildAgent
        value: bastionvm
  - ${{ else }}:
      - name: buildAgent
        value: accvm

stages:
 - stage: "BuildStage"
    displayName: "Build Stage"
    jobs:
      - job: "BuildJob"
        displayName: "BuildJob"
        pool:
          name: deployment
          demands:
            - Agent.Name -equals $(buildAgent)
        steps:
          - script: echo "Hello from the $(Agent.Name) build agent!"

In this example I'm using the predefined variable $(Agent.Name), which is populated with the name of the agent that is registered with the pool.
If that doesn't work try the following instead (assuming you have a name capability set with the build agent name):
demands:
  - name -equals $(buildAgent)

